# Share disk among Windows EC2 Instances

Tags: windows, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I am planning to use a 36 vCPU EC2 instance for compiling a large C++ project on Windows (7, 10 or Server). Due to high cost, this instance will only run when we need it, and then for 1-2 hours. From time to time we need to do maintenance on the C drive, such as downloading and installing software, removing files etc. That can take time and it will be costly if we run 36 vCPUs for this purpose. Actually 1 vCPU would be enough.

Is it possible to use the same disk as C drive for multiple EC2 machines? This way I can do the maintenance with the 1 vCPU instance. Machines will not run concurrently. The only difference will be the number of vCPUs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EBS volumes cannot be shared between running EC2 instances. An EBS volume can only be used by a single EC2 instance at any given time.

You could stop your EC2 instance, detach the volume, and attached it to another EC2 instance.

However, for your use-case, there is an easier solution: EC2 instances can change the instance type (for example, from m4.xlarge to t2.small, and back).

When you want to perform maintenance, you could:

1. Stop your powerful EC2 instance (if it's running)
2. Change the EC2 instance type to a smaller type (done via the Actions menu in the AWS Management Console)
3. Start your EC2 instance.
4. RDP into the instance and perform your maintenance.
5. When the maintenance is complete, stop the EC2 instance.
6. Put the EC2 instance type back to the powerful instance type.

Please note, depending on the EC2 instance types, you may also need to adjust the "EBS Optimized" flag on your EC2 instance.

For example, M4 instances support EBS optimized, but T2 does not. So if you switch between these two types, you also need to adjust the EBS optimized flag as well.

The above is a perfectly valid use-case in lowering your EC2 instance costs.

Answer (score 1):

Instance switching as suggested may be the best solution here. You can also script it so that the process can be further simplified.